# Remove module dependency in multi-site D7 setup?

Tags: 7, multi-sites, files

In sites/all/modules, I have video module 7.x-2.2 installed. Within my sub-site in a single-core, multi-site setup, I have video module 7.x-2.7 installed. When I try to disable and remove the local video module (7.x-2.7) - for a lack of words, it wont' let me, nor default back to the sites/all/modules/video module. I get wsod, database errors, and funky behavior. How would I remove my subsites manual dependency on its local module? Is my last resort to go into the database? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Without disabling the module, remove the code for your local video module, leaving the code you want in sites/all/modules. Next, run `drush registry-rebuild` followed by `drush updatedb`.  See: http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild

IMPORTANT NOTE: Your globally installed video module is 7.x-2.2, but your local module is 7.x-2.7.  You can't go backwards in version numbers in Drupal, so you'll have to upgrade your global video module to 7.x-2.7 and run updatedb on all other sites that use it before following the instructions above. If you can't upgrade the global module, you'll have to keep them separate until you can.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, I didn't know it was poor practice to go backwards in version #s, and thanks for that registry_rebuild, gives some peace of mind!